# Logstash HTTP Output Failure

Tags: logstash

I'm using **logstash 6.5.4** in centos7 for collecting the information from system and sending it to node server through **http output plugin**. following is my code.

```
input {
    stdin{}
}


output{ 
    stdout{}
    http {
        url => "http://nodeserver.example.in:5000/send"
        format => "json"
        http_method => "post"
        headers => ["Authorization", "Bearer ${CLOG_TOKEN}"]
        content_type => "application/json"
    }
}
```

with the **stdout{}** plugin I'm getting output on console, 
but with **http{}** plugin I'm getting *http output failure* error

```
[2020-05-27T16:19:37,789][ERROR][logstash.outputs.http    ] [HTTP Output Failure] Could not fetch URL {:url=>"http://nodeserver.example.in:5000/send", :method=>:post, :body=>"{\"@version\":\"1\",\"host\":\"vm2\",\"message\":\"hello\",\"@timestamp\":\"2020-05-27T10:49:32.699Z\"}", :headers=>{"Authorization"=>"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTMxNjgzODIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoic3lzYWRtaW4iLCJvcmdOYW1lIjoiUHJvdmlkZXJPcmciLCJyb2xlIjoid3JpdGVyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTkwNTc2MzgyfQ.vNaPEBhxG26oUYNKBYHKFtE0FH8mqHsKJRd45UjWFZE", "Content-Type"=>"application/json"}, :message=>"Connection reset", :class=>"Manticore::SocketException", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/manticore-0.6.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:37:in `block in initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/manticore-0.6.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:79:in `call'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-http-5.2.3/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb:239:in `send_event'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-http-5.2.3/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb:175:in `send_events'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-http-5.2.3/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb:124:in `multi_receive'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:114:in `multi_receive'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:97:in `multi_receive'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:373:in `block in output_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1343:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:372:in `output_batch'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:324:in `worker_loop'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:286:in `block in start_workers'"], :will_retry=>true}
[2020-05-27T16:19:37,869][INFO ][logstash.outputs.http    ] Retrying http request, will sleep for 0 seconds
```

my server is working fine through the curl command I'm able to send the data.
and also I tried the same code in other system with **logstash 6.8.9 version**, there it is working without any issue.

can any one suggest why this error is occurring?

Comment: not sure what it is but you might want to do this exact thing from a POSTMAN (I know you mentioned you did it through curl and worked). Try with Postman, with the headers info you have here. take the output from console that gets generated for `stdout` and use those headers info that you are trying use in your `http` output.

Comment: @JBone thanks for your attention but Postman could not solve my problem because logstash runs continuously and for every single event log it generates the output data set, so for every output I can't use the curl command or Postman tool. In logstash there is inbuilt HTTP output plugin is available to send the data to server. In my case the issue is with that plugin.